# MySQL How to use LIKE with ending charaters

Tags: mysql, sql-like

EDIT: the problem came from my database configuration, case closed, thanks!

I have the following data set:

```
Roma
Romagnano
Romano
```

When I use the following LIKE statement: `LIKE 'rom%'`

I get:

```
Roma
Romagnano
Romano
```

However, when I use the statement  `LIKE 'roma%'`

I get:

```
Romagnano
Romano
```

What LIKE statement should I use in my query to keep the line "Roma" in my results and keep the following result set if the search is based on "roma":

```
Roma
Romagnano
Romano
```

Should I use REGEXP instead? Many thanks

Comment: `LIKE 'roma%'` should also return `Roma`, if it doesn't then the problem is somewhere else. You don't need any different query for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the exact configuration on your system is, but on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/32711) the following returns all three values:

```
select *
from (select 'Roma' as val union all
      select 'Romagnano' union all
      select 'Romano'
     ) r
where val like 'roma%';
```

Comment: *`don't know what the exact configuration on your system`*, Does behavior of `%` depends on MySQL version?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan . . . Well, it might depend on the default collation for the database.  It might depend on whether special characters are in the strings.  And it might depend on system variables that I am unaware of.  I guess I didn't phrase the idea perfectly, but the code does work on at least one system, the SQL Fiddle system.

Answer (score 3):

Something is your MySQL configuration seems to be different, since both the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) and a simple [SQLFiddle test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/21507/0) say otherwise: it should work.

Comment: That's correct. `LIKE 'roma%'` should also return `Roma`